# Getting HTTP Status 404 - / error message when hitting URL http://localhost:8080/ in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

when i try access my webapplication with link http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/login.do It works fine but when i try to access default page in tomcat with  URL http://localhost:8080/ i am getting below error

**UPDATE:-** i am using springsource-tc-server-developer

*type Status report

message /

description The requested resource (/) is not available.*

As per  my understanding it should give me the default welcome page. Should i need to configure anything for this?

Comment: Do you get your welcome page if you hit  `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp/` ? If the answer is yes, then I suspect your context root is `MyWebApp`. This will typically be the case if you simply copied a war file called `MyWebApp.war` into `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps`. The application that shows up in the `/` context is called `ROOT`. So if you deploy a file called `ROOT.war`, it will be browsable at `http://localhost:8080/`.

Comment: Hi Asaph i get my application login page with http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp not the tomcat welcome page.

Comment: Did you delete ROOT or ROOT.war?

Comment: No i did not.  where i can find path for variable CATALINA_HOME as i dont have it in my environment variables

Comment: $CATALINA_HOME is your tomcat installation directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hitting /admin for Tomcat Admin page.

If your using new install Tomcat 7, try [installing the manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access).

Comment: getting same error with http://localhost:8080/admin

Comment: hmm, try /manager. In your tomcat_home/webapps folder do you have the "manager" directory?  or the "root" directory.

Comment: yes i have manager directory inside webapps. It also did not work. I tried both links http://localhost:8080/manager and http://localhost:8080/ROOT but getting same error.

Comment: Are you using tomcat 7? I'm more familiar with older versions.  I think you need install manager app, http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

Comment: using tomcat 6 lying in springsource-tc-server-developer